# Wrong injectors in 2 ports

Tags: fuel-injectors, cadillac, gasoline-direct-injection, escalade

I have a 2015 Cadillac Escalade luxury 4wd with 6.2 regular gas. I  changed 2 injectors but by mistake the 2 i installed are high flow and the correct one should be low flow what is the worst that csn happen if i leave like that?

Answer (score 1):

Two of your cylinders will run rich due to more fuel being added than the ECU expects.
This could cause numerous serious problems.  For example -

1. The catalytic converter will work harder to burn the unburnt fuel.
   Maybe causing the Cat to burn out.
2. The ECU may recognise the rich exhaust caused by the 2 new injectors and weaken the mixture.  This
   could make your correct injectors run weak causing high temperatures in the other two cylinders
   leading to burnt pistons and valves.